# how to clone a gene fragment in two direction as sense and antisense in vector

Tags: molecular-biology, rna-sequencing

I have a sequence ATG GGG CCC TTT AAA TAA and want to use it as antisense RNA in my vector. How should I clone it? I am confused with the direction of my clone. I looking for the direction and sequence of the clones.

Comment: Perhaps place a promoter or ori upstream in the antisense direction?

Answer (score 2):

Tour sequence's complementary is TAC CCC GGG AAA TTT ATT. Together they form a DNA strand. Now replicate this and then, after transcription of both the DNA you get the RNA sequence you wanted. Use it as sense or antisense.

Comment: Is there something missing from "transcription of both the DNA"?